# APC UPS reports battery charge 000.0%

Tags: linux, battery, ups

I have a Back-UPS CS 500 attached to a Linux PC (openSUSE 13.1 x86_64) that since this morning reports

```
BCHARGE  : 000.0 Percent
TIMELEFT :   0.0 Minutes
```

The other values seem normal to me:

```
$ apcaccess
APC      : 001,045,1097
DATE     : 2016-06-15 13:04:52 +0000  
HOSTNAME : myhost
VERSION  : 3.14.10 (13 September 2011) suse
UPSNAME  : myups
CABLE    : USB Cable
DRIVER   : USB UPS Driver
UPSMODE  : Stand Alone
STARTTIME: 2016-06-15 12:05:21 +0000  
MODEL    : Back-UPS CS 500 
STATUS   : ONLINE LOWBATT 
LINEV    : 226.0 Volts
LOADPCT  :  16.0 Percent Load Capacity
BCHARGE  : 000.0 Percent
TIMELEFT :   0.0 Minutes
MBATTCHG : 5 Percent
MINTIMEL : 3 Minutes
MAXTIME  : 0 Seconds
OUTPUTV  : 230.0 Volts
SENSE    : Medium
DWAKE    : 000 Seconds
DSHUTD   : 000 Seconds
LOTRANS  : 180.0 Volts
HITRANS  : 266.0 Volts
RETPCT   : 000.0 Percent
ITEMP    : 29.2 C Internal
ALARMDEL : 30 seconds
BATTV    : 12.0 Volts
LINEFREQ : 50.0 Hz
LASTXFER : Low line voltage
NUMXFERS : 0
TONBATT  : 0 seconds
CUMONBATT: 0 seconds
XOFFBATT : N/A
SELFTEST : NO
STESTI   : None
STATFLAG : 0x07000048 Status Flag
MANDATE  : 2010-08-17
SERIALNO : 4B1034P03420  
BATTDATE : 2010-08-17
NOMOUTV  : 230 Volts
NOMINV   : 230 Volts
NOMBATTV :  12.0 Volts
NOMPOWER : 300 Watts
FIRMWARE : 808.q8.I USB FW:q8
END APC  : 2016-06-15 13:05:08 +0000
```

Is this maybe some firmware bug? The value "000.0" seems really odd...

---

**Update**

Now the battery seems to have recharged a bit, but it seems stuck at 14%:

```
$ apcaccess 
APC      : 001,045,1089
DATE     : 2016-06-16 19:19:03 +0000  
HOSTNAME : myhost
VERSION  : 3.14.10 (13 September 2011) suse
UPSNAME  : myups
CABLE    : USB Cable
DRIVER   : USB UPS Driver
UPSMODE  : Stand Alone
STARTTIME: 2016-06-15 14:08:31 +0000  
MODEL    : Back-UPS CS 500 
STATUS   : ONLINE 
LINEV    : 226.0 Volts
LOADPCT  :  17.0 Percent Load Capacity
BCHARGE  : 014.0 Percent
TIMELEFT :   5.5 Minutes
MBATTCHG : 5 Percent
MINTIMEL : 3 Minutes
MAXTIME  : 0 Seconds
OUTPUTV  : 230.0 Volts
SENSE    : Medium
DWAKE    : 000 Seconds
DSHUTD   : 000 Seconds
LOTRANS  : 180.0 Volts
HITRANS  : 266.0 Volts
RETPCT   : 000.0 Percent
ITEMP    : 29.2 C Internal
ALARMDEL : 30 seconds
BATTV    : 12.2 Volts
LINEFREQ : 50.0 Hz
LASTXFER : Low line voltage
NUMXFERS : 0
TONBATT  : 0 seconds
CUMONBATT: 0 seconds
XOFFBATT : N/A
SELFTEST : NO
STESTI   : None
STATFLAG : 0x07000008 Status Flag
MANDATE  : 2010-08-17
SERIALNO : 4B1034P03420  
BATTDATE : 2010-08-17
NOMOUTV  : 230 Volts
NOMINV   : 230 Volts
NOMBATTV :  12.0 Volts
NOMPOWER : 300 Watts
FIRMWARE : 808.q8.I USB FW:q8
END APC  : 2016-06-16 19:19:03 +0000
```

Answer (score 2):

No, this is normal behavior.

Your battery dates from 2010 and it simply died. A battery expectancy date for a UPS is typically about 5 to 6 years.

Your battery needs replacement. I'm not familiar with this type of UPS, so I don't know if they sell replacement batteries or that you need to replace the whole unit. If replacing the battery is possible, it will be cheaper.

Comment: It takes an [APC RBC2](http://www.apc.com/shop/ca/en/products/APC-Replacement-Battery-Cartridge-2/P-RBC2/?gclid=Cj0KEQjw-YO7BRDwi6Stp7T296ABEiQAD6iWMTvHZ_lZJ1z0WJSqSW__U3YN82uS3zpd_914JbfXrTYaAnBw8P8HAQ)

Comment: Generally, APC are pretty good about replacement batteries.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't noticed it was an APC.